# Print each pass of Merge Sort and Quick Sort algorithms

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to output each pass of a Merge Sort and Quick Sort algorithm I wrote for a homework assignment, but I'm having a little difficulty figuring out what exactly to print, when to print it, and where to place the print statement. In addition to printing the values, I'm also required to surround the arrays created by the algorithm in brackets with each pass, like the following:

Merge Sort Sample Desired Output:

```
[ 4     85     94     68     76     75     40     66     18 ]
[ 4     85     94     68     76 ] [ 75     40     66     18 ]
[ 4     85     94 ] [ 68     76 ] [ 75     40 ] [ 66     18 ]
[ 4     85 ] [ 94 ] [ 68 ] [ 76 ] [ 75 ] [ 40 ] [ 66 ] [ 18 ]
[ 4     85 ] [ 94 ]    
[ 4 ] [ 85 ]  
[ 4     85 ]    
[ 4     85     94 ] [ 68     76 ] [ 40     75 ] [ 18     66 ] 
[ 4     68     76     85     94 ] [ 18     40     66     75 ]
[ 4     18     40     66     68     75     76     85     94 ]
```

Quick Sort Sample Desired Output:

```
[ 47     44     39     77     80     19     49     45     65 ]
[ 44     39     19     45 ] [ 47 ] [ 77     80     49     65 ]
[ 39     19 ] [ 44 ] [ 45 ] [ 47 ] [ 49     65 ] [ 77 ] [ 80 ]
[ 19 ] [ 39 ] [ 44 ] [ 45 ] [ 47 ] [ 49 ] [ 65 ] [ 77 ] [ 80 ]
```

My class is just barely getting into stacks and recursive functions, so I'm currently just a little stuck. Here are my two functions for each sorting algorithm:

Merge Sort Algorithm:

```
public static void MergeSort(int[] array) {
    int size = array.length;
    if (size < 2)
        return;
    int mid = size / 2;
    int leftSize = mid;
    int rightSize = size - mid;
    int[] left = new int[leftSize];
    int[] right = new int[rightSize];

    for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
        left[i] = array[i];

    }

    for (int i = mid; i < size; i++) {
        right[i - mid] = array[i];
    }

    MergeSort(left);
    MergeSort(right);
    Merge(array, left, right);
}

public static void Merge(int[] array, int[] left, int[] right) {
    int leftSize = left.length;
    int rightSize = right.length;
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    while (i < leftSize && j < rightSize) {
        if (left[i] <= right[j]) {
            array[k] = left[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        } else {
            array[k] = right[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }
    }

    while (i < leftSize) {
        array[k] = left[i];
        k++;
        i++;
    }

    while (j < rightSize) {
        array[k] = right[j];
        k++;
        j++;
    }
}
```

Quick Sort:

```
public static void QuickSort(int[] array, int left, int right) {
    int pivotIndex = left + (right - left) / 2;
    int pivotValue = array[pivotIndex];

    int i = left;
    int j = right;

    while(i <= j) {
        while(array[i] < pivotValue) {
            i++;
        }

        while(array[j] > pivotValue) {
            j--;
        }

        if(i <= j) {
            int tmp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = tmp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }

        if(left < i) {
            QuickSort(array, left, j);
        }

        if(right > i) {
            QuickSort(array, i, right);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all your merge algorithm isn't correct ;) Try it with your sample data and print the result and then you will see that the resulting array is not right. Printing that exact desired output will be a bit hard because of the way the recurrsion works - it always finishes the left part until the end and then starts with the right part. So printing  [ 75     40 ] [ 66     18 ] on the same line as [ 4     85 ] [ 94 ] [ 68 ] [ 76 ] is pretty much impossible because they are calculated in different steps in the recursion tree

Comment: I think I fixed my mistake as far as getting the actual sorting correct. I guess there's not really a way to have each pass printed, even if its not all fancy with the brackets?

Comment: You can print each pass but it will print different result than what you have written. Because that's not the way the algorithm goes through the data. It first goes to the left until it reaches a single number and then starts going backwards on the right parts.

Comment: This is the output I get when I print the value of `array` at the very bottom of the `Merge` method: [OUTPUT](https://imgur.com/a/RQ9s2bx).  Is that as close as I can hope to get for what I'm doing?